# Paste columname in R

Tags: r, loops

There is a data frame with predictors (these are factors) and they all have a specific column name:

```
colnames(te)
[1] "XEF1" "TYI4" "KOP4" 
[3] "GGF19" "TRR129"
```

If I try in a loop:

```
for (i in 1:2){
glm(GGF19~factor(paste(colnames[te][i])),data=te)
}
```

Error:

> Error in model.frame.default(tf, dati) : variable lengths differ (found for 'factor(colnames(te)[i])')

Instead if I write it with the name hard coded:

```
for (i in 1:2){
    glm(GGF19~factor(TYI4),data=te)
    }
```

It works. How can I get that to work in the loop? I already tried as.name but that caused the same error.

Comment: you can try something like `glm(as.formula(paste("GGF19 ~ factor(",colnames(te)[i],")"), data=te)`

Comment: can I also do this recursively? so as to add XEF1 in the example to the right sitee or d te equation? as well as TYI14?

Answer (score 0):

I tried looping names over one of my own dataset , following code works fine:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {

      print(colnames(data)[i])

}
```

Why are you using paste ? Return type of both paste and colnames is character.

Comment: that does not work for me, still get the same error Error in model.frame.default(tf, dati) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'factor(print(colnames(te)[i]))')

Comment: Okay, first question, are you trying to access just two columns here     
    for (i in 1:2){
    glm(GGF19~factor(paste(colnames[te][i])),data=te)
    }
Also, in the place where you have hardcoded
    for (i in 1:2){
    glm(GGF19~factor(TYI4),data=te)
    }
It looks like you want to fit linear model but calling that statement two times. What exactly are you trying to do here ?